# Powershell 5.0 Invoke-Command Start Service with Credential

Tags: powershell, service, credentials, invoke-command

We have a problem with a Service on a Server. So we decided to write a PS-Script that a "normal" User without Admin privileges can start this Service. I have practiced now 2 Day's on this little Script. I'm a newbie (Apprentice) in PS but im glad that it works when I run it as an Admin. But why the heck not as an User?

I have generated the "Secure" Password as follow:

```
"P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Temp\Password.txt"
```

I took the SecureString and pasted it in my Script that looks like this:

```
 $User = "DOMAIN\USER"
    $PwHash = "01000000d08c9ddf0....."
    $MyCredential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, ($PWHash | ConvertTo-SecureString) 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "MyServer" -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name "MyService" | Set-Service -Status Running} -Credential ($MyCredential)
```

The failure pops up by the $MyCredential row:
ConvertTo-SecureString: Key in specific Status is not valid.

I have nowhere read that for an ConvertTo... cmd are Admin rights needed.
Enable-PSRemoting is active on the specific Server.

Thanks for your time and engagement

Dirty.Stone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you're going about this all wrong.  This is an example of the kind of task you would use JEA (Just Enough Admin) for. Create a constrained, delegated session on the target server, configured with a function for starting or restarting that service and running under a local account that has permission to control the service, and then grant the non-admin users permission to use that session.

Comment: Thx mjolinor for this hint. I dindn't hear about this but it looks very intresting. How would it look by the end-users?? Do I understand this right, that I will also make a Script that they can run or will they Start/Restart the service otherwise? Greetings

Comment: You can make a script for them that will invoke the command on the remote machine through that session using Invoke-Command, or they can use Enter-PSSession to open a remote command prompt on that machine and work interactively. You can configure the session so that they will only have access to command or functions that you specify in the session configuration.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will evaluate that with my boss... !